# set cookie and redirect in express

Tags: express, cookies, server, jwt

I'm trying to set a cookie to the response and redirect the user if they haven't been verified (inside the route)

```
//add jwt token on successful login
res.cookie('jwt', user.token)
console.log(user)
if(user.security.active === false ){
  res.status(401).json({error: 'your account has been deactivated'})
}
//if user.security.verified == true
if(user.security.verified === false){
   res.redirect('/verify');
}

if(user.security.approved === false) {
   res.redirect('/approval')
}

res.redirect('/')
```

I get an error on my server  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

does this mean I can't use redirect when I set the cookie?

Answer (score -1):

wait sorry, added return before each res and it now works as it should

if anyone would like to contribute a comment to further explain anything please do.

Comment: What do you mean by "added return before each res"? Each res after the `res.cookie` call?